# How to represent outliers for multi dimensional data (local outlier factor)

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, outliers

Below graph taken from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_outlier_factor displays "LOF scores :

LOF image :

[image]

This is great for two dimensional data but what about data > than two dimensions. How can this be represented ?

I'm considering below type graph where each circle represents a reach-ability distance (distance value is currently not displayed on this graph). The radius of the circle is equal to the current lof value. Since this graph is plotted on multi-dimensional data it cannot be plotted on a 2d graph.

[image]

Are there other methods of representing distances for multi dimensional data ?

Comment: LOF scores aren't distances. Mixing distances and non-distances this way is confusing to the reader, and will yield incorrect conclusions ("if the core distance is larger than the LOF value, ...")

Comment: Plus, how would you visualize multi-dimensional *points*?

Comment: @Anony-Mousse "how would you visualize multi-dimensional points" that's what I don't know. I'm just wondering are there graphs available that display lof for multi-dimensional data. I just want to know how they appear so I have something to work from. The image "LOF image" in original question is very clear in how it represents the data for two dimensions. But is there a a similar representation graph for multi-dimensional data ?

Comment: You can't visualize LOF well, except for toy data sets like this, IMHO. Have you had a look at ELKI? Maybe it contains some similar visualizations for more complex data, too (the Wikipedia figures was made with ELKI, which is the best tool for outlier detection IMHO)?